# Clearing out result from WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I have the follow code section for a web client:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => 
client_DownloadProgressChanged(sender, args, this.Context.ConnectionId);
client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, evt) =>
{
    byte[] result = evt.Result;
    aLongRunningTask(result);**
}
```

My problem is that the "aLongRunningTask" function needs to be initiated upon the completion of the downloaddata method, which is working fine, but since the file I receive is very large, I end up having a string in memory taking up a lot of memory space, that there is no need for since I only need byte[].

evt.Result is sadly a readonly property so I can not empty it, and I can not null the client, since I am running the aLongRunningTask.

Is there any way to either overwrite the evt.Result so it can be cleaned, or another way to get that memory usage emptied.

Comment: Execute `aLongRunningTask` in a non-blocking (=asynchronous) way. So that `DownloadDataCompleted` can quickly complete.

Comment: tried it, but then it seems to loose connection with interface

Comment: It looks like you didn't post the full relevant code. What do you mean by loosing connection with interface ? Can you post the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `using`
like this

```
using(var client = new WebClient()){

//your logic

}
```

Comment: Thank you,but no, it wont change anything. Using will run the code in the same way as above, so wont be able to free the memory before it is done completing the longrunningtask